# Devise session links

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just installed devise in my existing journal . i created a folder named home and create an index.html.erb inside of it. I go to routes.rb and put root to: home#index . Then all of a sudden whenever i create a link regarding devise session ,for example <%=link_to new_user_session_path %> it always go to localhost:3000 . I tried to remove the root to: home#index that i put in route.rb but it always go to localhost:3000 whenever i go to any devise session links . What did i do wrong ?

Comment: What does `rails routes` or `rake routes` spit out?

Comment: hi thanks for response . I just shut down my computer then when i turn it on and go back to my codes its working . its weird but thank you